# “android.view.InflateException: Binary XM file line” na altura de mudar de atividade

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

Estou neste momento a desenvolver uma app para Android e estou com um problema que acaba por fazer o meu programa deixar de funcionar a partir do momento em que carrego no botão "SignIn".

A App não tem problema nenhum na altura de chegar à atividade principal, mas acaba sempre por "crashar" na altura de carregar o botão.

Basicamente existe algum tipo de problema com o código que me está a escapar e infelizmente o Android Studio acaba também por não dar qualquer pista relativamente ao problema em si para além do log que vocês podem ver aí em baixo.

```
> 05-12 18:42:57.687 32378-32378/com.cars.evd.dealership
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.cars.evd.dealership, PID: 32378
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cars.evd.dealership/com.cars.evd.dealership.main.SignIn}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Binary XML
> file line #53: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
>      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
>      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>         at com.cars.evd.dealership.main.SignIn.onCreate(SignIn.java:25)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>      Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 1 to color: type=0x5
>         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:473)
>         at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
>         at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.<init>(FButton.java:52)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>         at com.cars.evd.dealership.main.SignIn.onCreate(SignIn.java:25) 
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009) 
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000) 
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**Manifest**

> ```
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
>     android:supportsRtl="true"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <activity android:name=".SignIn">
>     <intent-filter>
>         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>     </intent-filter>
> </activity>
> </application> 
> </manifest>
> ```

**MainActivity.Java**

> ```
> Button btnSignIn, btnSignUp;
> TextView txtSlogan;
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>     btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
>     btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
>
>     txtSlogan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSlogan);
>     Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/NABILA.TTF");
>     txtSlogan.setTypeface(face);
>
>
>     btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>
>             Intent SignUp = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
>             startActivity(SignUp);
>         }
>     });
>
>     btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>
>             Intent SignIn = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignIn.class);
>             startActivity(SignIn);
>         }
>     });
>
> } }
> ```

**activity_main.xml**

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/imageView"
>         android:layout_width="200dp"
>         android:layout_height="200dp"
>         android:src="@drawable/logo" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/txtSlogan"
>         android:layout_width="200dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:text="@string/slogan"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
> </LinearLayout>
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:orientation="horizontal"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:weightSum="2"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
>         style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_margin="8dp"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:background="@color/btnSignActive"
>         android:text="@string/SignUp"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>        />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
>         style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_margin="8dp"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:background="@color/btnSignActive"
>         android:text="@string/SignIn"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>        />
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

**SignIn.Java**

> ```
> public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {
> EditText edtemail, edtPassword;
> Button btnSignIn; 
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
>
>     edtPassword = (MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
>     edtemail = (MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.edtemail);
>     btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
>
>
>     //Init Firebase
>     final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
>     final DatabaseReference table_user = database.getReference("User");
>
>     btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>
>             final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignIn.this);
>             mDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
>             mDialog.show();
>
>             table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
>
>                 @Override
>                 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
>
>                     //check if user not exist in database
>                     if(dataSnapshot.child(edtemail.getText().toString()).exists()) {
>                         //get user information
>                         mDialog.dismiss();
>                         User user = dataSnapshot.child(edtemail.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
>                         assert user != null;
>                         user.setName(edtemail.getText().toString());
>                         if (user.getPassword().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
>                         } else {
>                             Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Wrong Password !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                         }
>                     }else{
>                         Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "User not exist in Database !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                     }
>                 }
>
>                 @Override
>                 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
>
>                 }
>             });
>         }
>     });
>
> } }
> ```

**SignIn.xml**

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
>     android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
>     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>     <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
>         android:id="@+id/edtemail"
>         android:hint="@string/name_of_e_mail"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
>         android:text="@string/daniel25_gmail_com"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>         android:textSize="34sp"
>         android:inputType="phone"
>         app:met_baseColor="@android:color/white"
>         app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
>         app:met_maxCharacters="11"
>         app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/white"
>         app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
>         />
>
>     <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
>         android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
>         android:hint="@string/password"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
>         android:text="@string/_1234"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>         android:textSize="34sp"
>         android:inputType="textPassword"
>         app:met_baseColor="@android:color/white"
>         app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
>         app:met_maxCharacters="11"
>         app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/white"
>         app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
>         />
>
> </LinearLayout>
> <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
>     android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
>     android:text="@string/SignIn"
>     android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>     android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_margin="8dp"
>     app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignActive"
>     app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
>     app:shadowEnabled="true"
>     app:shadowHeight="5dp"
>     app:cornerRadius="4dp"
>     /> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como descrito [aqui](https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button/issues/41), é um problema com a biblioteca FButton que está usando. Siga o link para obter alternativas.

Comment: Agradecido pela resposta, está totalmente correto.
O problema que tinha devia-se relativamente ao FButton e a nova biblioteca solucionou todos os problemas.


Cumprimentos